# iTunes unable to see latest backup

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

Hi I have a problem with restoring a backup on my phone right now. This is my situation:

I recently upgraded my iPhone to iOS 10. After a while I didn't like the interface so I wanted to downgrade it to the previous OS which is 9.3.5.

Before I did that I backed up my files with iTunes and proceed to revert my iPhone back to iOS 9.3.5. After reverting, i tried to restore my backup but iTunes couldn't see my backup file that I did before reverting.

On my iTunes, it shows that I have two backups: one on iCloud in April and the other was before I reverted to iOS 9. I can find both backups in the backup folder but iTunes can only see the one in April.

Please help me with the problem. I have tried various solution but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The backup from April is visible because it was made with iOS v9.x. The backup from before you downgraded was made with v10.x.

You cannot downgrade and then restore a backup from before you downgraded. It is not compatible with the version of iOS that you are running.